# How to use mulitple entity manager in services symfony 4

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have setup two entity managers in `doctrine.yml`
I have to inject repository into service but problem is repository always taken an default entity manager. 
How should I give specific entity manager to repository.
In symfony 4 we can treat repository as service using `ServiceEntityRepository`

Comment: So you have the same entity mapped in multiple managers?  That is indeed a problem with using ServiceEntityRepository.  Check the constructor and you will see that the first manager that maps the entity is used.  You can write your own constructor if the repository knows which manager to use.  Or you can [wire up your repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738243/error-injecting-repository-into-service-with-symfony3-3/45739225#45739225) the old fashion way using a factory.

Comment: Not the same entity, I am having different entities for different managers. defining the old fashion way using a factory, works. thanks

Comment: Might want to double check your mapping.  If a given entity is only mapped in one entity manager then the out of the box ServiceEntityRepository will work.  I suspect you may have multiple mappings without realizing it which could cause unexpected behaviors down the road.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to inject `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry` in your construct. And then use `$managerRegistry->getManager('your_connection_name');`

For example:

```
//use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
private $connection;
function __construct(ManagerRegistry $em)
{
    $this->connection = $em->getManager('your_connection_name');
}
```

Comment: Your update for Symfony 4 doesn't work in a general service -- `$this->getDoctrine()` isn't magically imported just because you inject an entity manager. 

The doc you supplied is showing `Controller` that extends `AbstractController` that utilizes the `ControllerTrait` that has the `getDoctrine()` helper method that does `$this->container->get('doctrine')`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than lazy/auto loading them, you'd need to setup each as a named service and [explicitly configure their loading](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#explicitly-configuring-services-and-arguments) in your `services.yaml` file.